# How to make check if a key exists in mapping or not in Solidity when value is of type enum?

Tags: solidity

I have the following contract in solidity.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract PocketCrypto {
    enum Role{ GUARDIAN, WARD} 

    mapping(address => Role) public role;

    function setRole(Role _role) public {
        role[msg.sender] = _role;
    }
}
```

I want to check if for a given `address` a `Role` is set or not. But since default value for mapping will be 0, and for enum it will mean first `Role`, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the enum to reflect the 0th index (default) value as none.

```
enum Role{ NONE, GUARDIAN, WARD}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But if some dev tries to read that contract, he/she may think that there can be a case where there is no role. In my case, I strictly have a role for each address. In that case, also, will it be a good practice to use NONE?

Comment: @adzo261 Then comment the line stating the `NONE` value as a placeholder and that there are no users with this role.